# Can't do the chat on fitness stackexchange

Tags: support, chat

[image]When I attempt to chat on I get turned into a different user and it says I don't have enough rep (20 rep is required, on fitness I have 136) to chat. Does anyone know why this would happen.

P.S.  It says that I don't have enough rep on stackexchange

Comment: I would have said it's because you're using a mac, but... I would have just been kidding :)

Comment: @NathanWheeler you don't know I'm using a mac you just know I'm using OSX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had two different accounts on our network, and you were logged in as one on some sites and as the second on others. One of the accounts was identified with an @gtempaccount.com email address, so you are having an issue similar to [this Google user](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/hxWmreBIuoQ).

I have merged the accounts, so that both email addresses (the real one and the gtempaccount one) are now associated with the same Stack Exchange account. If you want to remove one of them, you can do that by clicking "my logins" in you user profile.

The reason that you couldn't chat was simply that you were logged in to chat.stackexchange.com as the other user, who indeed didn't have enough reputation. Since the accounts are merged now, you should be yourself again and be able to chat.

Comment: Thanks that @gtempaccount.com address is always coming up and bothering me